# cant seem to make this work.. blank page

Tags: php, phpseclib

I downloaded the phpseclib package and created this sample php script

```html
<?php

include('X509.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$csr = $x509->loadCSR('-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----');

print_r($csr);
echo $x509->validateSignature() ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
?>
```

I saved the file as test.php and i have X509.php in the same directory but when i open test.php i just see a blank page.. am i missing something? basically just following the examples on the website..

-- ERRORS IN CONSOLE --

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\Crypt\RSA.php on line 232
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\Crypt\RSA\MathLoader.php on line 120
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\Crypt\RSA\Key.php on line 211
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\Crypt\RSA\Key.php on line 301
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\Crypt\RSA\KeyPair.php on line 207
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\Crypt\RSA\KeyPair.php on line 279
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\Crypt\RSA\KeyPair.php on line 294
>
> Deprecated: Non-static method Crypt_RSA_MathLoader::loadWrapper() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Crypt\RSA.php on line 195
>
> Deprecated: Non-static method Crypt_RSA_MathLoader::loadWrapper() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Crypt\RSA\MathLoader.php on line 97

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the beginning of your Code. Now you should see the error instead of a blank page.

Comment: Blank page may mean some syntax errors. Errors and warnings usually appear in ....\logs\php_error.log or ....\logs\apache_error.log depending on your php.ini settings. You may want to check them

Comment: updated my post with the actually errors i see in the console.. any ideas why this is happening for a simple script.. i am following the example from this sample [link](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/examples.html#readcsr)

Comment: i didnt touch my php.ini file.. it didn't say to do so in the example..

Comment: okay, i seemed to get it working by moving it one directory closer to File/X509.php .. didnt like it any further than that.. but the content is all wrapped up and not visually nice to read.. any suggestions on a clean output.

Comment: look at the sourcecode.

Answer (score 0):

You must have PEAR's Crypt_RSA package installed. phpseclib's Crypt_RSA does not have half of those files. Check it out:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/1.0/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php

No MathLoader.php, no Key.php, no KeyPair.php, etc.

Contrast with PEAR's Crypt_RSA. It has all of them:

https://github.com/pear/Crypt_RSA/tree/master/Crypt/RSA

So my recommendation: uninstall PEAR's Crypt_RSA. Or if you need it maybe consider using phpseclib 2.0 - a namespace'd version of phpseclib:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/2.0